# Replace values in a sampled subset

Tags: r, sample, replace

I have a dataset of 2000 individuals. 330 of them have missing data for the vector that I have named y.n.17 (culture results). I would like to replace 17 of the 330 missing (NA) values with a "1", indicating the result is a positive culture.

This is the line of code I am trying to use:

```
y.n.17[sample(is.na(y.n.17),17)]=1
```

It seems to replace 17 individuals with "1" every 100 individuals, whether or not they are NA! 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `is.na` returns logical.  `which(is.na())` returns numeric.  Sample from that.

Comment: You probably mean sampling "without replacement" here, right? I guess it's just a confusing juxtaposition of words. If not, `sample` allows you to set `replace=TRUE`. See `?sample`.

Comment: have a look at `is.na(y.n.17)` and see what that gives you.  What is the result of sampling from that?  What is the result of then passing that sample as an index to a vector (or list or data.frame)?

Comment: Thank you. It was a logical, and adding the "which" got me my numeric. That command still replaces more than the 17 of the 330 patients with missing data, and also patients without missing data. I chose 17/330 because the incidence of "+" cultures is about 5.2 %in the rest of my sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `n` be the length of `y.n.17` and `m < n` be the number of `NA` in that vector. `is.na(y.n.17)` is a boolean vector of length `n` containing `m` `TRUE` and `n-m` `FALSE`. When you sample from that vector by doing `sample(is.na(y.n.17),17)` you are getting a vector of length `17` of randomly selected `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Most likely a lot of `FALSE` and maybe just one `TRUE`. When you do `y.n.17[sample(is.na(y.n.17),17)]=1`, that vector of length `17` is recycled so `1` is inserted at regular intervals...

You mean to do:

```
na.idx      <- which(is.na(y.n.17))
replace.idx <- head(sample(na.idx), 17)
y.n.17[replace.idx] <- 1
```

Note: doing `head(sample(na.idx), 17)` is generally more robust than `sample(na.idx, 17)` as it will also work when your data has less than 17 `NA`s. But if you prefer your code to error out if it is the case, then do `y.n.17[sample(which(is.na(y.n.17)), 17)] <- 1`.

Comment: Thank you, both your original and your edited answer worked perfectly. ( I added the "which" to the original answer.)